# How to resolve pandas broadcast error with .apply()?

Tags: python, pandas, nltk

I am working on a toy code for creation of word synsets from strings... following below approach:

- tokenize words, generate POS tags in a dataframe
- apply wn.synsets to create a new column containing list of probable synsets

The code however has proven to be unreliable, works fine with some strings but then crashes on others with a broadcast error citing dimension mismatch. Am interested in knowing the exact cause of error.

Here's the code:

```
def conv_tag(tag):    
    tag_dict = {'N': 'n', 'J': 'a', 'R': 'r', 'V': 'v'}
    try:
        return tag_dict[tag[0]]
    except KeyError:
        return None
```

```
def doc_to_syns(doc): 
    doc_tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(doc)
    df=pd.DataFrame(nltk.pos_tag(doc_tokens))
    df[2]=df[1].apply(conv_tag)
    df[3]=df.apply(lambda row : wn.synsets(row[0],row[2]), axis = 1)
    return df
```

```
doc_to_syns('Bacon and eggs with a dose of Iodine')
```

Comment: A sample of the DataFrame would be helpful to run testing with. Also both code snippets currently have indentation errors.

Comment: The dataframe is generated from the string 'Bacon and eggs with a dose of Iodine'.. have corrected the formatting as well.. each row corresponds to a token created by nltk.word_tokenize()

Comment: I can't replicate the issue. Is this one of the strings that raises an error on your end?

Comment: yes this is the one 'Bacon and eggs with a dose of Iodine'. infact, the error goes away if i delete the word Bacon